# Grails - rendering a model and a variable

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

What is the correct way to give a model to a GSP via the controller but also supply a variable. I have one that is not part of the model, but also needs to be rendered by the GSP.

What I started with:

```
def index = {
      render controller:"test", action:"index", model:[user:user]  
}
```

For an example - how I modified it (incorrectly) I think

```
def index = {
      def url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      render controller:"test", action:"index", model:[user:user, testvar: url]  
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your modified version?  Because that should work correctly.  Using `${testvar}` in the GSP should show up as `http://www.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: I took the dumb pill this morning. My simple example works. I had a little more code I left out for brevity. The problem was related to something else. Is there some documentation on passing multiple items into model. Couldn't find anything in my Grails book. I was just guess when I tried the testvar thing.

Comment: Well, I guess this lives on as an example for others to find. Going to step away from the computer now and take a break. Recharge the brain before I ask something else.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you should be able to write things like this:

```
def index = {
      def url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      return [user:user, testvar: url]  
}
```

By default, Grails view will automatically get the variable returns from the relevant action. This is done automatically by mapping view path - controller/action name.

If you call "render", it's a bit different. You can render any view which may not associated to your controller/action. I recommend only using it when in need.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right. That will send the var in the model to the gsp, but if you want to send it to the javascript as in a `remoteFunction`, you need to use `grails.converters.JSON` as next:

```
render [var1:value1, var2,value2, ...] as JSON
```